# A short exact sequence regarding Kähler differentials and an invertible ideal on an algebraic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors, short-exact-sequences

$\def\sO{\mathcal{O}}
\def\sK{\mathcal{K}}
\def\sC{\mathscr{C}}$I am trying to understand what the maps are on a certain s.e.s. of sheaves of modules on an algebraic curve. It is \eqref{ses} on Conrad's *Grothendieck Duality and Base Change*, p. 227. I'm unable to find any other similar-looking s.e.s. or any reference on books, the Stacks Project, Google or Stack Exchange.

Here's the context in which the s.e.s. is stated: let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $X$ be a reduced and proper $k$-scheme of dimension $1$. Denote $\pi:\tilde{X}\to X$ to the normalization of $X$. In particular, $\sO_X\subset\pi_*\sO_{\tilde{X}}$ and the latter is the integral closure of $\sO_X$ in $\sK_X$. We define the *conductor ideal*
$$
\sC=\operatorname{Ann}_{\sO_X}(\pi_*\sO_{\tilde{X}}/\sO_X).
$$
This ideal sheaf cuts the non-normal locus (equivalently, the non-smooth locus, since $X$ is a curve) of $X$ (Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, Ch. V, §1, no. 5, Corollary 5). We have that $\sC$ is a $\pi_*\sO_{\tilde{X}}$-module and that it is $\sO_X$-coherent (so is the annihilator of a coherent module on a locally Noetherian scheme; use [0H2L](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0H2L)). Hence, it is $\pi_*\sO_{\tilde{X}}$-quasi-coherent (see first lemma [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4789906/394668)). Therefore, there is an ideal sheaf $\tilde{\sC}$ on $\tilde{X}$ with $\pi_*\tilde{\sC}=\sC$ (ibid., second lemma); unique up to unique isomorphism. Now Conrad argues “since $\tilde{\sC}$ is a coherent ideal sheaf on the smooth curve $\tilde{X}$ and is generically non-zero, it is an invertible sheaf.”

My first question is:

> (Q1). Why does it follow $\tilde{\sC}$ is invertible?

I get that if $S\subset X$ denotes the singular locus of $X$, then $\tilde{U}=\pi^{-1}(X\setminus S)\subset\tilde{X}$ is open dense and $\sC|_{\tilde{U}}\cong\sO_{\tilde{U}}$. But I don't see why does this imply that $\sC$ is globally invertible.

He continues: “Thus, there is an exact sequence
$$
\label{ses}\tag{5.2.2}
0\to\Omega^1_{\tilde{X}/k}\to\Omega^1_{\tilde{X}/k}(\tilde{C})\to\sO_{\tilde{C}}\to 0
$$
where $\sO_{\tilde{C}}=\sO_{\tilde{X}}/\tilde{\sC}$ is the structure sheaf of the finite closed subscheme $\tilde{C}\subset\tilde{X}$ defined by $\tilde{\sC}$ and $\Omega^1_{\tilde{X}/k}(\tilde{C})=\Omega^1_{\tilde{X}/k}\otimes\tilde{\sC}^{-1}$ is the sheaf of meromorphic differentials on $\tilde{X}$ with ‘poles no worse than $\tilde{C}$’ (where we view $\tilde{C}$ as an effective Weil divisor on $\tilde{X}$).”

My other questions are:

> (Q2). What are the maps in \eqref{ses}? I have no clue for any of them.
>
> (Q3). What does it exactly mean that “$\Omega^1_{\tilde{X}/k}(\tilde{C})=\Omega^1_{\tilde{X}/k}\otimes\tilde{\sC}^{-1}$ is the sheaf of meromorphic differentials on $\tilde{X}$ with ‘poles no worse than $\tilde{C}$’”?

Comment: Surely your second two questions can be found in Hartshorne Ch2?

Comment: Do you know for a one dimensional integrally closed scheme, all local rings at closed points are  dvrs?

Comment: @Mohan By "integrally closed scheme" do you mean a normal scheme? If so, wouldn't we need to further assume local Noetherianity to conclude that the stalks at all closed points are dvrs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subtlety here is that I don't think the second arrow in your short exact sequence is not supposed to be canonical. (It's not canonical in general, and I don't think the data of $\tilde{X} \to X$ is enough to make it so.) It is if $\tilde{C}$ is a reduced divisor, by the residue map, but that's probably not relevant here.

So one has the short exact sequence

$$ 0 \to \tilde{\mathscr C} \to \mathcal O_{\tilde{X}} \to \mathcal O_{\tilde{C}}\to 0$$

by definition.

Question: What invertible sheaf can we tensor the first term of this exact sequence by to get the first term of the desired short exact sequence?

Question: What happens to the second term if we tensor by the same invertible sheaf?

Question: What happens to the third term if we tensor by the same invertible (and thus locally trivial) sheaf?

For Q1, it is as Mohan says in the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456767/a-short-exact-sequence-regarding-k%c3%a4hler-differentials-and-an-invertible-ideal-on#comment1183046_456767) — it is a local question, and you can use local rings.

For Q3 it just means that for $I$ the ideal sheaf of a divisor $D$ and $L$ any line bundle, a section of $L \otimes I^{-1}$ gives a section of $L$ over the open set $\tilde{X}-D$, i.e. a meromorphic section of $L$. If we choose a local generator for $L$ at a point of $D$ and express this section as a rational function times the generator, the rational function may have a pole at that point (since it's not a section over that point) but the order of the pole is bounded by the multiplicity of the point in $D$ (again this is a local calculation and can be done in local rings).

Comment: $\def\sC{\mathscr{C}}\def\sL{\mathcal{L}}\def\sO{\mathcal{O}}$Thank you so much! I just proved to myself that $\pi^{-1}(V(\sC))=V(\tilde{\sC})$, and that this is a finite union of closed points. Invoking [0B8Y](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B8Y) now I can conclude that $\tilde{\sC}$ is invertible. On the other hand, I understand how one obtains the first and second terms on the sequence after tensoring by the line bundle $\sL=\tilde{\sC}^{-1}\otimes\Omega_{\tilde{X}/k}$. But why $\sO_{\tilde{C}}\otimes\sL=\sO_{\tilde{C}}$?

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo $\mathcal O_{\tilde{C}}$ is a sum of  sheaves supported at different points. The tensor product of a sheaf with a sheaf supported at a point can be computed locally in a neighborhood of that point. But now choose a local trivialization of $\mathcal L$ in a neighobrhood of each point, so in that local calculation we may treat $\mathcal L$ as the trivial bundle.

Comment: $\def\sL{\mathcal{L}}$I've been thinking about it already for a while, but I achieved nothing. From the knowledge that $\sL$ is locally trivial in a neighborhood of each of the points in $V(\tilde{\mathscr{C}})$, how can we conclude that $\sL$ is locally trivial in a neighborhood of $V(\tilde{\mathscr{C}})$? (Local trivializations do not glue in general.)

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo You don't need to, since $\mathcal O_{\tilde[C}}$ is a sum and you can handle each summand separately. It is also possible to show local trvializations exist in a Zariski neighborhood of any finite set, but this is unnecessary. (E.g. pick an arbitrary affine neighborhood. A sheaf on an affine variety is generated by its global sections. Using this, one can check that there exists a section that is nonvanishing on your fixed finite set. Now just choose the neighborhood to be where the section is nonzero.)

Comment: $\def\C{\mathscr{C}}$Sorry to bother. I just realized that I was assuming all the time that $\C$ is radical (i.e., that $\C_x$ is a radical ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ for all $x\in X$, or, equivalently, that $\C(V)\subset\mathcal{O}_X(V)$ is radical for all open affine $V\subset X$). However, I'm not sure this is true in general. Only if $\C$ is radical I can conclude that $\C$ is invertible by invoking [0B8Y](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0B8Y) plus finiteness of the set of singular points of $X$. How does one show that $\C$ is invertible in general?

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo Discrete valuation rings are PIDs, so every ideal is invertible.

Comment: Right! Every ideal sheaf on a smooth curve is free of rank 1 using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784127/freeness-of-stalk-implies-locally-free#comment10178632_2784145). Thanks : )

Comment: Again, since I cannot use that $\tilde{\mathscr{C}}$ is radical, I don't know how to see that $\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{C}}$ is a sum. If $\tilde{\mathscr{C}}$ were radical, I guessed I could use some scheme-theoretic version of the Chinese remainder theorem after writing $\tilde{\mathscr{C}}$ as the intersection of the ideals associated to each of the points in $V(\tilde{\mathscr{C}})$. But this might not be possible.

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo Any sheaf supported at finitely many points is a direct sum over those points by considering the sheaf condition on an open cover where each open set contains only one of the points. You can also do this with the Chinese remainder theorem by writing the ideal as an intersection, for example using that the rings of sections are Dedekind domains.

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo Based on your questions I think you might be better served by reading a less advanced algebraic geometry book first.